# richfaces:toolbar background-color not rendered

Tags: css, richfaces

Hello guys i have a little css problem with the following toolbar:

```
<rich:toolbar id="navigationToolBar"> 
                       <rich:dropDownMenu mode="ajax">
                           <f:facet name="label">
                               <h:panelGroup>
                                   <a href="success.xhtml">HOME</a>
                               </h:panelGroup>
                           </f:facet>
                           <rich:menuItem  label="new" action="#">New
                           </rich:menuItem>
                           <rich:menuItem  label="open" action="#">Open
                           </rich:menuItem>
                       </rich:dropDownMenu>
                       <rich:dropDownMenu mode="ajax">
                           <f:facet name="label">
                               <a href="index.xhtml">CREATE MONITORING</a>
                           </f:facet>
                       </rich:dropDownMenu>
                       <rich:dropDownMenu mode="ajax">
                           <f:facet name="label">
                               <a href="monitorings.xhtml">SAVED MONITORINGS</a>
                           </f:facet>
                       </rich:dropDownMenu>
                       <rich:dropDownMenu mode="ajax">
                           <f:facet name="label">
                               <a href="networkmanagement.xhtml">MANAGE NETWORKS</a>
                           </f:facet>
                       </rich:dropDownMenu>
                       <rich:dropDownMenu mode="ajax">
                           <f:facet name="label">
                               <a href="edituserprofile.xhtml">EDIT PROFILE</a>
                           </f:facet>
                       </rich:dropDownMenu>
                       <rich:dropDownMenu mode="ajax">
                           <f:facet name="label">
                               <a href="administration.xhtml">ADMINISTRATION</a>
                           </f:facet>
                       </rich:dropDownMenu>
                   </rich:toolbar>
```

So I'm trying to set the css within the css file like this:

```
.rf-tb{
    background-color: purple !important;
    border-color: orange !important; 
}
```

The modification of the border works but the background is not changed to purple, when i press ctrl+f5 for a second i can see that it is purple but then it renders back to the original color. Do you have any idea what else should i set to make it work?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The default background of the toolbar is an image, the purple background you're setting hidden is behind it. You have the override the background-image as well.

Either

```
background-color: purple;
background-image: none;
```

or simply

```
background: purple;
```